# Azure feature to download a file daily

Tags: azure

I'm new with Azure and I do not have extensive programming skills so please be indulgent with me.

I need to download a csv file from a public website (no authentication) that gets updated daily. I assume that I need Azure because I don't want to keep my computer running everyday to make sure it downloads and I cannot miss a day as the file gets replaced with the new one.
The file can be outputed to Azure or cloud storage like dropbox. I will then use it in Sql Server Integration Services.

Do you have a recommendation on how to proceed?

Here is an example of the file: http://www.msss.gouv.qc.ca/professionnels/statistiques/documents/urgences/Releve_horaire_urgences_7jours.csv

Comment: This is a very broad and opinion-soliciting question, with lots of ways to accomplish this. There's no "right" answer - only discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Logic Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/) for this purpose, no development at all is required for your requirements.

This is how you could design your Logic App:

- **Recurrence**: Trigger the flow every 24 hours
- **HTTP**: Create a http request to download the file content
- **Dropbox - Create file**: Upload the file to your dropbox account

[image: Logical apps workflow]

Comment: Great thanks! I did not know the Logic Apps. Do you know how I can put the current datetime in the file name when creating file on dropbox?

Comment: you can use Azure functions to extend the functionality, an example can be found here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2016/08/16/extending-azure-logic-apps-using-azure-functions/

Comment: You can specify the name of the file that will be sent to Dropbox in the Logic App Dropbox action: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/connectors-create-api-dropbox/

Comment: I was looking for a solution that would not add an additional action to the workflow. There is no way to do it directly in the Dropbox create file action?